# Show the first N groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id serial,
  type text,
  tid int,
  amount text,
  effective_at timestamp without time zone
);

INSERT INTO test (type, tid, amount, effective_at) VALUES (null, null, 2.0, '2020-01-01 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO test (type, tid, amount, effective_at) VALUES ('rev', 1, 2.0, '2020-01-01 20:00:01');
INSERT INTO test (type, tid, amount, effective_at) VALUES ('body', 1, 2.0, '2020-01-01 20:00:02');
INSERT INTO test (type, tid, amount, effective_at) VALUES (null, null, 2.0, '2020-01-01 20:00:02');
INSERT INTO test (type, tid, amount, effective_at) VALUES ('rev', 2, 2.0, '2020-01-01 20:00:02');
INSERT INTO test (type, tid, amount, effective_at) VALUES ('body', 2, 2.0, '2020-01-01 20:00:02');
INSERT INTO test (type, tid, amount, effective_at) VALUES ('body', 3, 2.0, '2020-01-01 20:00:03');
```

In the following, the ordering for this table is by `effective_at`.

---

**Query result**

```
select * from test order by effective_at;
```

| id | type | tid | amount | effective_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:00.000Z |
| 2 | rev | 1 | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:01.000Z |
| 3 | body | 1 | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:02.000Z |
| 4 | null | null | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:02.000Z |
| 5 | rev | 2 | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:02.000Z |
| 6 | body | 2 | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:02.000Z |
| 7 | body | 3 | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:03.000Z |

---

Is it possible to get the first **3** groups with the same `tid` but `tid` with null values should be considered a different group?

```
1st group is: id 1
2nd group is: id 2, id 3
3rd group is: id 4
```

So expected result is:

| id | type | tid | amount | effective_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:00.000Z |
| 2 | rev | 1 | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:01.000Z |
| 3 | body | 1 | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:02.000Z |
| 4 | null | null | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:02.000Z |

Also, it should be possible to do offset of the groups. For example, skip the first two groups and get the next 1 group:

| id | type | tid | amount | effective_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | null | null | 2.0 | 2020-01-01T20:00:02.000Z |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enumerate the groups.  My suggestion is to use `lag()` and then a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_tid = tid then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(tid) over (order by id) as prev_tid
            from test t
           ) t
      ) t
where grp <= 3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b006818b6599e3cb02b08bac227b2f7d) is a db<>fiddle.